# Deleting "Android\sdk" folder from the path "C:\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk"

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-10

Will it cause any problem if I delete the **"Android\sdk"** [**Size: 2 GB**] folder from an *old directory path* **"C:\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk"** ?
I actually do have another **"Android\sdk"** folder [**Size: 23 GB**] on a different location [**Local Disk D**] since previously I faced **WHITESPACE NAMING ISSUES** while using Android Studio. So I think the folder is lying idle on my Local Disk C. Should I delete the folder on the path **"C:\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk"** ? Or, will it harm the **IDE** in the future ?

Answer (score 1):

No it will not harm your development and IDE, but make sure that before deleting this sdk folder, the Android Studio SDK path has been set to the other targeting SDK. You can completely delete the one which you are not using.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make a link folder to your main android sdk folder (23gb). you can put that link in place of your first folder (2gb). even you can have your main folder in a path with spaces, but you've to create a link folder for some where like c:\android\sdk and in your favorite IDE sets the path to that. It's a OS level abstraction and everything works like a charm on top of that

For example:
mklink /j C:\android-sdk "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk"

Comment: By link folder, do you mean a "shorcut" folder ?

Comment: I added a sample. (-:

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can remove your older Android SDK Folder (2 GB). There is no longer a need for it as the Android studio is targetting the new location PATH ("D" Directory) so, Feel free to remove the older one.